# laravel cant send users name in related products

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4, laravel-7

i use this code but i cant send users name in related products 
i use this code

```
  Creator: {{$product->users->name ?? ''}}
```

i cant show creator of products 
for productscontroller i use this:

```
public function index(){
        $products = Product::with(['users'])->get();
        return view('products.index', compact('products'));}
```

and for model product

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

and for model user

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

and table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('weight');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

this error see

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:

Comment: You have named your relationship `users` while you want to access data through `user`.

Comment: @AlexGholamian thank you but i changed but this error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:

Comment: Are you sure the assigned user exists in the database?

Comment: @AlexGholamian yes i have 3 user in users table and 5 product in products table

Comment: You did not set the foreign key in your migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the foreign key in your migration:

`Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); // <- HERE
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('weight');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });`

And your relation should be named `user` (**Singular**) not `users`